# converting datatype while calculating hashCode

Tags: java, hash, dictionary, bit-manipulation, hashcode

While calculating hashcode for an object if we have an attribute whose type is long then we can convert it to int by below methods:

```
 1. int k = (int) (l);
 2. int k = (int)(l^(l>>>32));
( l is an attribute of the object whose datatype is long)
```

It is advisable (Joshua bloch in Effective Java)to use 2nd method. what's the reason behind this? My thought i have produced below, please provide your input whether my assertion is correct or not?

You can add to it if you have something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advisable to use 2nd method because it distributes the selection of bits well as it considers upper 32 and lower 32 bits much more than the 1st method which just considers the lower 32 bits.

> `l >>> 32`  ::   is dismissing the lower 32 bits or selecting higher
>    32 bits.
>
> `l ^ (l>>>32)`  ::  is XORing higher 32 bits to lower 32 bits which
>    gives you more distribution in-terms of selecting the overall bits
>    than just taking lower 32 bits which the first method does.

Answer (score -1):

I actually don't believe it's advisable in every situation.. If I had to choose between those two, I'd go for the first (you'd better use something completely different, though) when the longs are both positive and negative. This because if you would use the `L ^ (L>>>32)`, and you have the long values -1 and 0, or any combination that is `n` and `-(n+1)` (at least where `n<2^32`), the hash would result in the same value because of the two's compliment encoding. I guess pairs with `n` and `n+2^32` are less common.